# Apache Zeppelin: very slow html output

Tags: apache-zeppelin

My goal is to take some data from python and/or scala interpreter in Zeppelin, and to finally display the data inline by some JavaScript library such as Plotly, D3, Vis, etc.

The perfect seamless integration would be to simply output the JavaScript incl. the stringified data via `print("%html <script>" + content + "</script>")`.

Indeed, this works very well with all kind of libraries as long as the content is not too large, e.g., `print("%html <script>alert(JSON.stringify({name: 'Peter', age: 24}))</script>")`

However, if the content size grows, then the html output takes very, very long, e.g.:

```
%python
print("%html start")
s = "X" * 100000 # data of length 100k
print("<script>js='" + s + "'; alert(js.length)</script>") # takes > 1 minute!
```

Note that if I write the same output to a file and load it, there is no such delay. Thus, it is not caused by slow browser rendering, but probably by Zeppelin's way how %html output is processed?

Does anybody know how to fix or circumvent this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally found the answer: this is a known bug.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-1360

A workaround is to use the `%pyspark` interpreter for python development, rather than the pure `%python` interpreter.